# Calculate volume of tank by depth

Tags: geometry

I want to calculate the volume of a fuel tank as shown in the picture below. Essentially the two ends are irregular trapeziums.

[image]

Note that the depth changes (310mm vs 370mm) and the bottom width (480mm at one end and 20mm at the other, which is not visible).

The top surface of the tank has a ultrasonic sender which can measure the distance from the top of the tank to the top of the fluid in the tank.

If this distance d is known, and the dimensions are known as per the picture - is it possible to come up with a forumla to calculate volume of fuel in the tank in litres L?

Comment: Is this really an algebraic geometry question?  Aren't the bounding surfaces all supposed to be planar?

Comment: well, in any case it will be a piecewise formula

Answer (score 0):

Each of the quadrilaterals of tank should be specified using **five** dimensions, including diagonals or non- redundant ( max three) angles.

Comment: It has four sides, so what is the fifth dimension?

Comment: Assuming that each of the tank walls is planar, either a diagonal or an angle at one vertex is needed. Five dimensions determine a planar quadrilateral.